# How do I center my content inside the menu?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to figure this little bugger out for a little while, and now I seek some expertise. What am I trying to do? I want to create a 100% width menubar, but keep the logo, and the content centered so it can fit in with  the rest of the content. The container is on 1000px. Right now I have placed my menu outside of the container tag, and used "width: 100%" to get it to cover the screen. However with that the content moves to the left. I don't really know how to fix this, I have been working on it for a while.

Here is my HTML code:

```
    <body>
    <!-- navigation / header -->
    <div class="grid_12" id="menu">
        <div class="grid_3" id="logo">
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" />
        </div>

        <div class="grid_9 omega">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li>
                    <label>
                        <a href="#">Features</a>
                        <br />Check our features
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>
                        <a href="#">Pricing</a>
                        <br />Starts at $X/month
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>
                        <a href="#">30-day free trial</a>
                        <br />Start using us right away
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li class="sign-btn">
                    <a href="#">Log in</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="container clearfix">
```

and here is my css file:

```
#menu {
width:100%;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
padding: 0;
background: #1d3853;
color: white;
font-size: 13px;
}
.nav li {
padding-top: 15px;
list-style:none;
float: left;
text-align: center;
margin-right: 20px;
}
.nav li a {
color: #a7c5e3;
font-family: helvetica;
font-weight: bold;
letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.sign-btn a {
color: #FFF;
display: block;
background: #105296;
padding: 10px 15px;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 1px solid white;
}
```

So I ask again, dear StackOverflow... how do I get my links in the center with the rest of my content. Like this picture: http://www.cssnewbie.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/centered-navbar-sketch.png

Comment: In what way are the links not in the center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write your navigation code inside another `div` with `class=container`.

That is

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<!-- your navigation code here-->
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

To center something with a set width, add the style `margin:auto`. To be more precise, you only need `margin-left:auto` and `margin-right:auto` to give equal padding to an element inside a container.